# Grails: Fetch domain object from service init method

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have created a service where in its init method it tries to load an object from the database, but this error is thrown:

```
Caused by IllegalStateException: Method on class [pruebainitservice.Conf] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
->>   15 | init      in pruebainitservice.ConfService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I have created an example project, that basically does this; it just contains a domain class, a service, a controller with an action and its view. You can download from here https://github.com/okelet/grails-test-service-init.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Grails version: 2.3.8
Groovy Version: 2.1.8 JVM: 1.7.0_55 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

Regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `@PostConstruct` annotation is using it's own `ClassLoader`, hence the exception.

I'd use `InitializingBean` interface to do the init you need:

```
class SomeService implements InitializingBean {

  @Override
  void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    doStuffHere()
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

the only solution I could find was to call the init-method from `BootStrap`:

```
class SomeService {

  void init(){
    log.debug("Cargando configuración...")
    def confs = Conf.findAll()
     // the rest
  }
}
```

and

```
class BootStrap {

  def confService

    def init = { servletContext ->
      confService.init()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn' work. It throws the same exception.

Comment: have you removed the annotation?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/okelet/grails-test-service-init/blob/master/grails-app/services/pruebainitservice/ConfService.groovy

Comment: Why are you injecting the `Conf conf` in your service? remove it

Comment: It is not (or at least, it is not supposed to be) injected, but an instance variable of the service. Can not this be done?

Comment: At least it works for my case. But for example, it wouldn't work for request or session scoped services, because where would you call the init method from? Can this be considered a bug?

Comment: request or session scoped services work fine, as they usually wrapped by `OSIV-Filter` which provides the TX-context. 
As I said, the problem with `@PostConstruct` (and `InitializingBean`) lays in the class-loader which is used. In order to get GORM-methods and alike, you must use `GrailsClassLoader` and not the one from your servlet container.
What I would suggest as an improvement/new feature, is to make `@PostConstruct` and others grails-aware

Comment: Or maybe a special grails annotation like `@BootStrap` or even a convention `def bootStrap( servletContext ){}` to include a service method into the init-run